# `require': cannot load such file even when using 'bundler'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

For reference, here is my replit environment: https://replit.com/@realquadrant/DefenselessGrowlingExtraction#main.rb

The problem:

I run the following script:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)

require 'instantiate_clients.rb'
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/runner/DefenselessGrowlingExtraction/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/trinsic_service_clients-1.1.5018/lib/generated/credentials.rb:14:in `require': cannot load such file -- timeliness (LoadError)
```

It looks as if, despite using "bundler" the required dependencies, such as "timeliness" have not been loaded to run the 'credentials.rb' script for 'trinsic_service_client'

Comment: 1) Is the gem in your Gemfile? 2) Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: The gem is not in my gemfile…it’s a dependency for the gem that is. That being said when I add the errors gemfile to my gemfile I no longer see the error. 

I did run bundle install. Thanks.